# WebView reset zoom setting

Tags: android, webview

I set WebView with this initial values

```
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

After the first loading, the web page shows as full page.
If I load a new Url the new page shows with the last zoom settings. It is not loaded with the initial setting. How can I reset the last zoom settings to initial value before loading the next url?

Answer (score 5):

try to set these properties-
 webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
 webview.setInitialScale(0);

Comment: That works! To reset zoom again later, one can use webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false); webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); webview.setInitialScale(0);

Answer (score 0):

In **Kotlin** you wan try :

```
webview.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
webview.setInitialScale(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my app, testing on Android 8, I tried all the combinations of the previous answers. `setInitialScale` made no difference and only this reset the zoom level before a new load:

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```